# Free member on submit blank page

Tags: freemember

I'm using Freemember to register members. I have my return parameter set up correctly (see below). When I submit the form the the member does get registered in the back end but the page just goes blank and remains at form page, does not go to the return page. I had this working and have disabled/uninstalled any other add-ons that I added since setting up Freemember. I don't understand why this is happening. Please help. Thanks.

Here's the form code:

```
{exp:freemember:register form_id="jumpstart_register" form_class="form" form_name="jumpstart_register" return="jumpstart/guidelines" error_handling="inline" error_delimiters="<span class='form_error'>|</span>" require="first_name|last_name|phone|email|password" group_id="7"}

            <label class="req" for="first_name">First Name</label><br />
            {field:first_name}
            {error:first_name}<br />

            <label class="req" for="last_name">Last Name</label><br />
            {field:last_name}
            {error:last_name}<br />

            <label class="req" for="phone">Phone</label><br />
            {field:phone}
            {error:phone}<br />

            <label class="req" for="email">Email</label><br />
            {field:email}
            {error:email}<br />

            <label class="req" for="password">Password</label><br />
            {field:password}
            {error:password}<br />

            <label class="req" for="password_confirm">Confirm Password</label><br />
            {field:password_confirm}
            {error:password_confirm}<br />

            <p><strong>Important Notice:</strong> It is in your best interests, as well as Ganeden's, that you have fully read, understood, and comply with the Submission <a href="{path='jumpstart/view/terms-conditions'}">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>. If there are any terms or conditions that you did not fully understand, please reread them, and if you are still uncertain, seek legal counsel before making a submission to this website.<br/>
            {field:accept_terms} <label class="req" for="accept_terms">I accept the <a href="{path='jumpstart/view/terms-conditions'}">terms &amp; conditions</a></label><br />
            {error:accept_terms}
            </p>

            <input type="checkbox" name="us_based" id="us_based" value="yes" /><label class="req" for="us_based">I and/or my company are based in the U.S.</label>
            <span id="us_based_error" class="form_error"></span><br />

        <div>
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
        </div>
    {/exp:freemember:register}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I also had mx-notify-control installed (not being used) and I missed it when I was going through and disabling add-ons. It was creating the conflict. Problem solved.